# arraylist java compiling errors

Tags: java, arraylist

ok i try to play with arraylist in java awhile to experiment some thing that related my project..so i come up with a simple code like this

having 3 file...DataStruc.java , DataStrucHand.java , testcase1.java

```
DataStruc.java


public class DataStruc {
private String testString;

public DataStruc(String s){
    this.testString = s;
}

public String getTestString() {
    return testString;
}

public void setTestString(String testString) {
    this.testString = testString;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s",testString);
}
}


DataStrucHand.java

 import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class DataStrucHand {
private ArrayList<DataStruc> ds;

public void addData(String ss){
    ds.add(new DataStruc(ss));
}

public ArrayList<DataStruc> getData(){
    return ds;
}
}


testcase1.java
 import java.util.*; 
 public class testcase1 {
public static void main(String args []){
    DataStrucHand dsh = new DataStrucHand();

    String gdata = "test";

    dsh.addData(gdata);


  }
   }
```

i tried to compile it and having this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DataStrucHand.addData(DataStrucHand.java:7)
at testcase1.main(testcase1.java:8)
```

can i know what is wrong actually? i cant even add the data...i am trying to add the data and retrieve it back by creating another testcase2.java...but than i having problems in adding now to the arraylist...my purpose is to create a temp storage to keep a specific string that can be obtain by 1 program but runs with 2 different classes..

Answer (score 2):

You never assign anything to the `ds` field.

DataStrucHand.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataStrucHand {
    private ArrayList<DataStruc> ds; //I am null because nothing is ever new'd up here...

    public void addData(String ss){
        ds.add(new DataStruc(ss));
    }

    public ArrayList<DataStruc> getData(){
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Try it with this line:

```
private ArrayList<DataStruc> ds = new ArrayList<DataStruc>();
```

Or, you can have a constructor that will new it up if you prefer that method:

```
public DataStrucHand() {
     ds = new ArrayList<DataStruc>();
}
```

Comment: oh my god, thanks for the help...is like 3.50AM here and i really need some sleep

Comment: @user1217609: You need sleep and to learn the steps on how to debug a NPE. The key is to check the variables on the line throwing the exception then trace back in the code to see why it's null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an `ArrayList<DataStruc>` instance in `ds`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated the ArrayList.  Write this:

```
public class DataStrucHand {
    private ArrayList<DataStruc> ds = new ArrayList<DataStruc>();

    public void addData(String ss){
       ds.add(new DataStruc(ss));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've never initialized `ds`, so it is null when you call `ds.add(new DataStruc(ss));` Add a constructor to `DataStrucHand` that initializes ds, such as `ds = new ArrayList<DataStruc>();`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `DataStrucHand` class never initializes its private field `ds`, so when you try to call `ds.add(...)` it fails with `NullPointerException`.

In fact, the way the class looks right now, there is no way `ds` can be anything else than `null`.

Shortest way to fix this is to initialize `ds` properly:

```
private final List<DataStruc> ds = new ArrayList<DataStruc>();
```

This way each `DataStrucHand` instance is constructed with an `ArrayList` inside and `ds` is never `null`.